# Why am I having issues with my while loops in this function?

Tags: c++

The function is meant to read in two values, minimum and maximum. If either value is less than two an error message prints and both values are read in again.

I've tried making a separate while loops for min < 2 and max < 2. I've tried parenthesizing each condition on each side of the or operator. I've tried declaring two variables withing the function and setting one as equal to max and one as equal to min, and using those new variables in the loops.

```
void read_range(int & min, int & max)
{
cout << "Enter minimum and maximum: ";
 cin >> min >> max;
  while (max < 2 || min < 2); {
    cout << "Error. Minimum and maximum must be at least 2." << endl;
    cout << "Enter minimum and maximum: ";
    cin >> min >> max;
  }
  while (max < min) {
    cout << "Error. Minimum must be less than maximum." << endl;
    cout << "Enter minimum and maximum: ";
    cin >> min >> max;
  }
}
```

the second while loop works fine.

There are 2 strange cases:
1. If either entered value is less than two, the program continues reading in values and must be manually stopped:

```
Enter minimum and maximum: 0 5
5 6
1 2
50 90
90 50
^Z
[23]+  Stopped
```

2. Even if both entered values are greater than two, the while loop still executes. The while loop does not execute again even if the re-entered value(s) is less than 2:

```
Enter minimum and maximum: 5 10
Error. Minimum and maximum must be at least 2.
Enter minimum and maximum: 1 2
(program continues running after this).
```

also, if the exact same values are re-entered then the while loop does not execute again:

```
Enter minimum and maximum: 5 10
Error. Minimum and maximum must be at least 2.
Enter minimum and maximum: 5 10
(program continues running after this)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could shorten that logic to `while (max < min || min < 2)`

Answer (score 2):

Your 1st loop has an erroneous `;` on it:

```
while (max < 2 || min < 2); {
```

It should be this instead:

```
while (max < 2 || min < 2) {
```

Answer (score 0):

while (max < 2 || min < 2); {

should be like this

while (max < 2 || min < 2) {

OUTPUT:

Enter minimum and maximum: 1
1
Error. Minimum and maximum must be at least 2.

Enter minimum and maximum: 10
5
Error. Minimum must be less than maximum.

Enter minimum and maximum: 5
12
**NO ERR**